# Using STS of Java EE app

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, ide

Recently I had the chance to write applications for Java EE and Spring.

Has the support of the STS IDE for Java EE apps/ Core Java?

By your experience is that stable/convenient for that target?

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STS is based on "Eclipse for Java EE developers" and you can install every plugin you need. From my experience it is a stable platform.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I used to work with MyEclipse so when you create an java ee project it generates for you 3 projects: the ear the ejb and the web. do you know a plugin that does this for you?

Comment: No, I do not. You can write a new question.